Current file name in Power BI report
I am struggling to get the current file name in the Power BI report.
I tried the following solutions:
FileName =
VAR FilePath = LEFT(PATH(), FIND("[", PATH(), 1) - 2)
RETURN
RIGHT(FilePath, LEN(FilePath) - FIND("", REVERSESTRING(FilePath), 1))
let
Source = #shared,

CurrentWorkbook = Source{[Name="CurrentWorkbook"]}[Content],

FileName = CurrentWorkbook{[Name="Name"]}[Content]

in
FileName

let
Source = #table({"FileName"}, {{Uri.LocalFileFromPath(#shared[Content])}})

in
Source

FileName = FIRSTNONBLANK(FileNameQuery[FileName], 1)
Current File Name = VALUE.NATIVEQUERYMETADATA()[Source.Name]
Current File Name Without Extension =
REPLACELASTSTRING(

    VALUE.NATIVEQUERYMETADATA()[Source.Name],

    ".pbix", ""

)



        In Power Query, create a new blank query
        Enter = [Source.Name] to create a column with the file name
        Remove any other columns
        Right-click the query and select "Reference" to load it into the model
        In DAX, reference this table, e.g. = 'Query Name'[Source.Name]

None of them are working. Any ideas?
DAX and M scripts have been provided by Google, Microsoft Forums, ChatGPT, Perplex and Copilot.

You can try to use the "Get data from folder" function in Power query.

With that you can select the directory where you saved the .pbix file and use some simple PQ to filter out the source name of the file.
If you need you can reference the official documentation.
